# "py-hungry-delete-backwards" instead " backward-kill-word" in python-mode.el

Tags: key-bindings, python

How can I replace `py-hungry-delete-backwards` for the traditional `backward-kill-word` in python-mode.el? I tried to define the <kbd>C-DEL</kbd> key in the python-mode hook but it just get ignored.

This is, I want to use the `backward-kill-word` command with <kbd>C-DEL</kbd> in a python environment.

Thanks!

Comment: Please show the actual code you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I found the solution in a bugreport:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda ()
            (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "<C-backspace>") 'backward-kill-word)))
```

For some reason my implementation of a similar hook was not working.

Comment: backward-kill-word should exist as M-backspace too.